# Which is larger: $n^{3/2}$ or $n^{\log n}$?

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

We know that $f(n)$ is $\mathcal O(g(n))$ if $\exists c\ge0$ s.t. $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)} = c.$$

Let $f(n)=n^{3/2}$ and $g(n)=n^{\log n}.$
When I am applying L'Hôpital's rule for  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^{{\log n}-3/2}}
=0.$$

If I apply L'Hôpital's rule for
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{g(n)}{f(n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^{3/2-{\log n}}} $$
then it seems to be $0$. Because $$\frac{\text{something}}\infty=0?$$

My question is how to prove $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^{3/2}}{n^{{\log n}}}=0$$ and $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^{{\log n}}}{n^{3/2}}=\infty$$ by L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: Welcome to the site! See @Nathaniel's answer: you're using a cannon to swat a fly.

Comment: If you take base two logarithm, as is customary in CS, then log n ≥ 2 > 3/2 whenever n ≥ 4. That's all you need.

Comment: Also $\lim_{n \to +\infty} n^{\frac{3}{2} - \log n} = 0$ (and not $+\infty$).

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/150069/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4386430/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  You already got extensive feedback on Math.SE but none of that seems to have influenced or been acknowledged in this question, even though those comments already lead the way to an answer.  It seems like you are wasting people's time by doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which is larger, $\frac32$ or $\log n$?

Is $x\mapsto n^x$ an increasing function or a decreasing function?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** $\log5>\dfrac32$.